# HttpServletRequest getCookies() always returns null Jersey Api

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I m able to add the cookie to response and view it on my chrome browser. I checked it through settings --> advancedSettings --> content settings.

```
@Context
HttpServletRequest servletRequest;
Cookie[] cookies = servletRequest.getCookies();
```

I m using @Context to get the request and getCookies() always returns null .

I m able to see the cookie in request headers in chrome using Inspect Element.

Comment: I m able to find the cookie in request header as map "cookie". I added multiple cookie and in this I have only one cookie. getCookies return null though. It is little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I was using @context UriInfo and uriInfo variable add a request with cookie part of its header.

I was able to extract the cookie as single String and do String manipulation over it but it works fine.

Still HttpServletRequest getCookies it didn't work.